# Custom unix command combination assigning to variable

Tags: bash, unix

I want to make UNIX script, which will automatically move my working directory files to newly created directories.

Example: In you dir you got files:

```
001-file.html,
001-file.rb,
002-file.html,
002-file.rb
```

And 2 files will be moved to ./NewDir/001-file and another 2 to ./NewDir/002-file

My problem is that after I get correct string from Unix commands I cannot assign it to variable.

Here is my code:

```
clear
echo "Starting script"
echo "Dir = "$(pwd)
read -p "Please enter count(max '999') of different file groups:" max_i
read -p "Enter new dir name:" outer_dir_name
for ((i=0; i<=$max_i;i++)) do
    a1=$(($i/100))
    a2=$((($i-$a1*100)/10))
    a3=$(($i-($a2*10)-($a1*100)))
    inner_dir_name=$((ls *[$a1][$a2][$a3]* 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -f1 -d"."))
    echo $inner_dir_name    
    echo "--------------"
done
```

Comment: 'Tis odd that you end your file names with commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pair of round parentheses is enough for command substitution.

```
inner_dir_name=$(ls *[$a1][$a2][$a3]* 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -f1 -d".")
```

Comment: Not so much 'enough' as 'the only correct number'; the `$((…))` notation is for arithmetic, but the expression isn't a valid arithmetic expression.

Comment: Tank you. You answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're going about the operation the hard way.  I would probably do something like this, assuming that there are no spaces in the file names:

```
ls | sed 's/\..*$//' | sort -u |
while read prefix
do
    mkdir -p $outer_dir_name/$prefix
    mv $prefix.* $outer_dir_name/$prefix
done
```

The `ls` could be made more precise with:

```
ls [0-9][0-9][0-9]-file.*
```

If I was worried about blanks and other odd-ball characters in the file names, I'd have to use something more careful:

```
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9]-file.*
do
    prefix=${file%%.*}
    [ -d "$outer_dir_name/$prefix" ] || mkdir -p "$outer_dir_name/$prefix"
    mv "$file" "$outer_dir_name/$prefix"
done
```

This executes more `mv` commands, in general.

Comment: Thank you. You did my project.(Answered in new way).